# Javascript: Empty an input field and press enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I use knockout framework. I have an observable array that can be filtered using ko.utils.arrayFilter
Now, I want to add a button to reset the array.
As the array gets reset when the input field is emptied using keystrokes, I wanted to simulate it with emptying the input field and then pressing the enter key

```
 self.resetFilter = function (){

         $('#filter').val('');
        var e = $Event("keypress");
        e.which = 13; 

        $("#filter").trigger(e);


    };
```

Not sure, if the code is wrong. Or if this is a problem with Knockout, as I am  not using Knockout to reset.

Below the entire code for the filtering function and the data binding in the HTML

Javascript

```
 self.stringStartsWith = function(string, startsWith) {
 string = string || "";
 if (startsWith.length > string.length)
    return false;
 return string.substring(0, startsWith.length) === startsWith;
 };



self.filter = ko.observable('');

self.filteredItems = ko.computed(function() {



var filter = self.filter().toLowerCase();

self.resetFilter = function() {

    $('#filter').val('');

    var e = $Event("keypress");
    e.which = 13; 

    $("#filter").trigger(e);


};


if (!filter) { 
    return self.venueList(); 
} else {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.venueList(), function(venue) {
        console.log(venue);
        return self.stringStartsWith(venue.name.toLowerCase(), filter);
        console.log(venue);
    });
}
}, self.venueList);

};
```

HTML

```
<li>
<input placeholder="Search" id="filter" type="text" data-bind="value:    filter, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" autocomplete="off">

<button data-bind="click: function(){resetFilter();}">Reset</button>
</li>
```

Comment: You need to trigger a change event after setting the value, and before triggering the keypress.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I do see that the input field gets emptied, so what does the change event do? I tried to wrap the keystroke code in a change function and tried to just add $('#filter').trigger('change()');, no success so far.

Comment: Should be `.trigger('change')` - no parentheses after "change".

Comment: I tried that as well, still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beauty of knockout is that you can use data-bindings to accomplish what you want to do. While it plays nicely with other libraries like jQuery, you can probably find a more elegant knockout-only solution. You mentioned that you're not using knockout to reset. Is there a reason for that?

Further, you can use the textInput binding instead of using `valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'` I'm not sure what your desired result is in terms of the flow of your search, but based on what you've provided in your question I put this example together. Pressing enter resets your filter - I'm not sure if that is your intended behavior as it seems a little strange from a UX perspective, but there it is nonetheless

```js
var ViewModel = function() {

  var self = this;
  self.filter = ko.observable();

  self.list = ko.observableArray([
    "fruit",
    "bread",
    "dad",
    "zoo",
    "keyboard",
    "monkey",
    "tiger",
    "apple",
    "bicycle",
    "father",
    "mother",
    "test",
    "computer",
    "programming",
    "ninja",
    "love",
    "earth",
    "nothing",
    "money"
  ]);

  self.filteredList = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.list(), function(item) {
      return item.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.filter()) > -1;
    });

  });

  self.clearFilter = function() {
    self.filter('');
  }

  self.onEnter = function(d, e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      //alert("You want to search for: " + self.filter());
      self.clearFilter();
    }
    return true;
  }

}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" data-bind="textInput: filter, event: { keypress: onEnter }" />
<input type="button" data-bind="click: clearFilter" value="Reset" />

<ul data-bind="foreach: filteredList">
  <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```